# Write an array to a non-contiguous range of cells

Tags: vba, c#-4.0, export-to-excel

I would like to **write data to a non-contiguous selection in Excel** which looks like this:

[image]

I tried to write a 2d array to that range but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Dim arr()
ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 5)
arr(1, 1) = 1
arr(1, 3) = 3
arr(1, 5) = 5

Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1,A3,A5")
r.Value = arr
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on msdn in C# and VBA: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/05/04/126190.aspx